# How can I specify a gid range in a sudoers Runas_Alias specification?

Tags: linux, centos, sudo, users

How do I allow *some_user* to run *some_command* as users with group ids comprised between 2000 and 2999 in a sudoers file ? Is it possible to specify a range of gids instead of a list in a Runas_Spec ?

```
Runas_Alias OTHER_USERS = %#2000, %#2001, %#2002, %#2003, %#2004, %#2005, %#2006, %#2007, %#2008

some_user ALL = (OTHER_USERS) NOPASSWD: some_command
```